# Tracking markers not matching in camera view

Tags: camera, tracking, effects

Camera tracking has been rather tricky. I tracked this relatively easy clip with a just a slight pan down. and got a solve error of .44. It just falls apart when i try to setup the scene. The tracking markers don't match the location from the clip when in camera view. Setting up the floor is just completely goes crazy. This is the video clip i'm using: https://www.pexels.com/video/people-walking-on-a-construction-site-8965524/

here's what i'm talking about.
[image]
[image]
Here's my solver settings (i've tried non tripod and results are even worse or track markers don't even show up if i uncheck tripod)
[image]

Comment: Sometimes, even after you have a good solve, it can still be a bogus solve. Not sure if you tried starting all over and getting a brand new solve, but I've had to do that and it saved a lot of time troubleshooting my previous "good solve."